# Google Prettify with Bootstrap: Line Numbers Not Showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prettify, google-code-prettify

I am using Google Prettify with Twitter Bootstrap. It is working, but for some reason, the line numbers are not appearing.

Here is the markup:

```html
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
    <ol class="linenums">
        <li class="L0">
            <span class="kwd">public</span>
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="kwd">override</span>
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="kwd">void</span>
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="typ">Dispose</span>
            <span class="pun">()</span>
        </li>
        <li class="L1">
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="pun">{</span>
        </li>
        <li class="L2">
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="kwd">base</span>
            <span class="pun">.</span>
            <span class="typ">Dispose</span>
            <span class="pun">();</span>
        </li>
            <li class="L3">
            <span class="pln"> </span>
            <span class="pun">}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</pre>
```

and I call it like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        prettyPrint();
    });
</script>
```

I don't have any custom CSS.. just using the Bootstrap CSS only..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I recommend you use those 2 files:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js

and add this in your footer:

```
<script>
  !function ($) {
    $(function(){
      window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()   
    })
  }(window.jQuery)
</script>
```

found in [application.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js) from http://twitter.github.com/

Comment: Can you please explain me what the script snippet is doing ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't have list-style: none; anywhere in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

The operative part of the default stylesheet is

```
li.L0,
li.L1,
li.L2,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L6,
li.L7,
li.L8 { list-style-type: none }
```

which turns off list bulleting for all items with index i where (i % 10) ∉ (4,9).

Adding a high priority style will override the default in prettify.css so you don't need to come up with your own theme.

```
<style>
li.L0,
li.L1,
li.L2,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L6,
li.L7,
li.L8 { list-style-type: decimal !important }
</style>
```

should do it.